# Disable all links on a list when any one is clicked

Tags: javascript

I've a list of links and I've created a function that does a link disabling. I've tried 'return false' and preventDefault() but it is preventing this from running Flask operations in the back end as well so I did replaceChild(). Can someone help me modify this function in a way that whenever anyone is clicked, the full menu is disabled?

```
<body>
<ul id="list">
        <li><a href="/home" title="Go Home"><image src="{{url_for('static',filename = 'logo.png')}}"; width="96px"; height="96px"></a></li>
        <li><a href="/pages">View Pages</a></li>
        <li><a href="/images">View Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="/lists">View Lists</a></li>
        <li><a href="/maps" onclick="loader(40);">View Maps</a></li>
        <li><a id="r1" href="/reload" onclick="switcherR()">Reload</a></li>
        <li><a id="r2" style="display: none;">Reload</a></li>
      </ul>
</body>
```

and the function switcherR is this:

```
<script>
function switcherR(){
    var re1 = document.getElementById("r1");
    var re2 = document.getElementById("r2");
    var lis = document.getElementById("list");

    r2.style.background = "#b3b3b3";
    r2.style.display = "block";
    r1.style.display = "none";

    lis.replaceChild(re2, re1);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not very clear your requirement. So if I click on `id=r1` link, what should happen?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath In my code, only r1 is getting deactivated as it is getting replaced by r2. I want to disable all the other links as well along with it. So when any link is clicked, the others become unavailable too.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to create CSS rule such as this:

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Then add to `<li>` tags a class (for example `menuItem`). And then in .js code use `addEventListener()` on your list where you will add a class 'disabled' to `menuItem` such as

```
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
     evt.target.menuItem.add(`disabled`);
});
```